# Only around 240 bytes are written when writing binary data

Tags: mysql, mfc, odbc, mariadb

I'm using MFC ODBC and MariaDB on a project. However, when I'm trying to write binary data, it will only write around 240 bytes and then finish writing. Here is the code I use:

```
            TRY
        {
        CLocalHistoryCurve rs_curve(NULL);
        if (rs_curve.IsOpen())
        {
            rs_curve.Close();
        }
        rs_curve.m_strFilter.Format(_T("furnace_number='%s' AND batch_number='%s' AND tube_number=%d"),
            str_f, str_b, n_t);
        rs_curve.Open();
        rs_curve.MoveFirst();
        rs_curve.Edit();
        rs_curve.m_velo_curve.SetSize(arr.GetSize());
        rs_curve.m_velo_curve.Copy(arr);
        rs_curve.Update();
        rs_curve.Close();
        }
            CATCH(CDBException, e)
        {
            wcout << e->m_strError.GetString() << endl;
        }
        END_CATCH
```

where `rs_curve` is a `CRecordset` derived class with RFX in it. `m_velo_curve` is a `CByteArray` member, which has 6040 bytes before I write it. There is no problem when opening this recordset and locating the record.
Here is the RFX function I use:

```
    RFX_Binary(pFX, _T("[velo_curve]"), m_velo_curve, 65535);
```

where `velo_curve` is a `BLOB` column with maximum capacity of 65535 bytes.
How can I write the 6040 bytes all at once to the column?
Also, please report any mistakes if you find any. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is byte #6040 a zero byte?  What are the limitations on `Copy()`?  (I haven't touched MFC or ODBC in 2 decades.)

Comment: 2 decades?! The m_velo_curve has zero bytes from the beginning, but it still can write, so I don't think zero byte can affect its behaviour. `Copy()` is a member function of `CByteArray`. and I'm sure it copies the exact amount of bytes to the destination.

Comment: This question is solved. It is a mistake when querying the data. The data actually updated correctly,

Answer (score 0):

This is because I'm using HeidiSQL to view the data, and it automatically adds delimiter `LEFT` to prevent slow loading. All 6040 bytes have written to the BLOB column correctly.
Question closed.